# PHP PDO Prepared Statements with Where IN Clause

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

This is my PHP PDO Code

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE tag1 IN ('$tag1','$tag2') $andor tag2 IN ('$tag1','$tag2 ') ORDER BY $sort DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start");
     // Then fire it up
     $stmt->execute();
     // Pick up the result as an array
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    // Now you run through this array in many ways, for example
```

I am trying to convert it into prepared statements, but I really don't understand, how it will work. I tried a lot of things from Google, but nothing worked.

Comment: You can start from [What prepared statements are](http://php.net/manual/it/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: `IN ('$tag1','$tag2') $andor`  what is the value of `$andor` and this does not look like a correct sql

Comment: is `$andor` a column?

Comment: No, if Tag 2 is empty, $andor = OR, if tag 2 is not empty, $andor = AND. Sorry for late response, I had to do some urgent work

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE tag1=? OR tag1=? AND tag2=? OR tag2=? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15,10");

$stmt->execute(array($tag1, $tag2, $tag1, $tag2));

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I hope it works.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'City' in 'where clause' in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\index.php:189 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\website\index.php(189): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\index.php on line 189

Comment: @Josh can u please attend my comments above